# Does this two equation system have a solution for l(1)?

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations

I'm having a debate with a friend over this problem:

$$\eqalign{
k(x) &= l(x)+8 \cr
l(x) &= 14-k(x)
}$$

What is the value of $l(1)$?

I think this isn't solvable because of the circular reference/dependency, but my friend thinks that it can be done with substitution, resulting in constant answers:

$$\eqalign{
l(x)&=14-[l(x)+8] \cr
2l(x)&=6 \cr
l(x)&=3
}$$
which leads to
$$\eqalign{
k(x)&=3+8 \cr
k(x)&=11
}$$

Thoughts?

Comment: Simply write $k$ and $l$ for $k(x)$ and $l(x)$ to see what is happening: $k-l=8$ and $k+l=14$. So $k=11, l=3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing circular in this problem since the two equations are different and cannot be derived from each other. Thus, using the substitution, it is true that $l(x)$ and $k(x)$ are always $3$ and $11$ respectively, which means that $l(1)$ is also $3$

Comment: Thanks, @fatso-boo.  I thought given the full substitution of these vague equations wasn't truly equivalent to substituting in like variables but couldn't say why.

Answer (score 1):

> I think this isn't solvable because of the circular reference/dependency

It's just a linear system of 2 equations in 2 variables, where it does not matter that $k$ and $\ell$ are functions.  One of the following cases will occur:

0. The system has no solutions because it's over-determined.  Example would be if the equations are, say $\ell=1$ and $2\ell=-1$ etc.
1. There is a unique solution
2. There is a space of solutions, i.e. the solution is not unique.  The equations just limit the degree of freedom of the 2-dimensional space in which $k$ and $\ell$ live.

In your case, the system of equations is

$$\begin{align}
k - \ell &= 8 \\
k + \ell &= 14
\end{align}$$

so that adding these equations gives an equation for $k$, and subtracting the equations gives an equation for $\ell$.  It is case 1. from above, i.e. the solution is unique.

If $k$ and $\ell$ are functions (of $x$), then they only satisfy the system of equations if they are constant functions with the values you computed.